# Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:. Required by: project :

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring and trying to use Spring Web dependency with spring boot.

Here is my build.gradle

```
    plugins {
       id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.7'
       id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
       id 'java'
}

    group = 'com.example'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

    dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring- boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

    tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

but when gradle sync, it returned errors

```
    spring-overview:test: Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
Required by:
    project :
```

And another error page here:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to resolve imported Maven boms: Connection refused: no further information
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.internal.DependencyManagement.resolveIfNecessary(DependencyManagement.java:157)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.internal.DependencyManagement.getManagedVersions(DependencyManagement.java:121)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.internal.DependencyManagementContainer.getManagedVersionsForConfiguration(DependencyManagementContainer.java:202)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.internal.DependencyManagementContainer.getManagedVersionsForConfiguration(DependencyManagementContainer.java:187)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.internal.DependencyManagementApplier$1.execute(DependencyManagementApplier.java:76)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.internal.DependencyManagementApplier$1.execute(DependencyManagementApplier.java:72)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:95)
    
    ... more
```

Comment: You probably have a gap in the implementation of the dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring- boot-starter-web'

Comment: can you please describe more? I also run into the same issue for a legacy project, thanks!

Comment: Remove this plugin `id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'` (not needed anymore and creates more problems than it solves).
Instead add this to dependencies:
`implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:<VERSION>')`
If you are also using annotationProcessors also add this:
`annotationProcessor platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:<SAME-VERSION>')`

Answer (score 0):

First for Spring boot use Eclipse or Spring Tool Suite which will be best for spring boot. And then if your Getting like this type of error.. then your spring boot haven't installed properly in out Editor. Better Try uninstall and reinstall or change your editor and STS or Eclipse...
Thank You... Further any clarification just comment below...

Answer (score 0):

seems like there is extra whitespace in spring-boot-starter-web
`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring- boot-starter-web'` . Can you remove he whitespace and do gradle build

Comment: The white space may be caused by copy and paste, I checked my IDEA, and there's no whitespace in this implementation.